# MacOS uninstalled after installing bootcamp during windows partioning

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

my mac's macos was uninstalled during setting up a new partition in windows, reason is windows reformatted the partitions to its format, is there a way for me to re-install macos without losing all data on windows, which by the way doesnt even have bootcamp drivers installed 
thanks!

Comment: Most of the time, Windows does not reformat. Instead, Windows changes the macOS partition type, which is a fixable error.

Answer (score 1):

This question if difficult to answer, because of the lack of information. The most likely answer is to boot to [macOS Recovery over the internet](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) and install macOS.

Other information that would have been helpful include the following.

- The version of macOS that was installed.
- The model/year of the Mac.
- The version of Windows.
- The Windows boot method (BIOS or EFI).
- The current entries in partition tables (GUID and MBR).
- The method use to install Widnows (DVD, flash drive, Boot Camp Assistant).

Comment: MacOS High Sierra running on a 2012 macbook pro 13 inch non retina, had windows 10 1903 installed using bootcamp (which failed to install drivers and the bootcamp.exe file so im running older drivers windows boot method im not sure about, thanks for the help!